# Call getString() alike method with an annotation like @Value in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Overridden getString()

```
public class MyProperties extends PropertiesConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MyDecryptor myDecryptor;

    public MarketPlaceProperties(URL url) throws ConfigurationException {
        super(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String key) {
        String value = super.getString(key);
        if (value != null) {
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("ENC\\((.+)\\)").matcher(value);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                value = myDecryptor.decrypt(matcher.group(1));
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

   //some code
}
```

We use to call this in the following way, which is fine. If I find the pattern then we decrypt the property value and return.

```
myProperties.getString("WS_USERID")
```

The question is: Now I want to set a property value using an annotation like below.

```
@Value("${MY_USERNAME}")
private String userName;
@Value("${MY_PASSWORD}")
private String password;
```

But the above @Value would set default value as it is from property file. However I want to call the method like above one to decode, not set the default one.

Can I have a custom annotation or any other solution?

Current Spring version: 4.1.4

Thanks.

Comment: are you using jasypt?

Comment: Yes, we use jasypt.

Comment: Not sure about default config, but you can definately use some custom annotation and implement your bean post processor for it

Comment: Jasypt will decrypt automatically, the variables in application.properties with the formt `ENC(....)`